# Given a list with a number of elements, how can I get the number of perfect triples?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I'm trying to solve a programming problem where given a list of integers, find the number of Perfect Triple `[x, y, z]` where `y % x == 0 and z % y == 0`

For example, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` has the triples: `[1, 2, 4]`, `[1, 2, 6]`, `[1, 3, 6]`, making the answer 3 total.

This is what I have so far:

```
def solution(l):
    l.sort()
    l.reverse()
    l_size = len(l)
    count = 0

    if len(l) < 3:
        return count

    for i in xrange(len(l) - 2):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, len(l) - 1):
            if l[i] % l[j] == 0:
                for k in xrange(j + 1, len(l)):
                    if l[j] % l[k] == 0:
                        count += 1

    return count
```

The problem with my solution is that the length of `l` could be between 2 and 2000 inclusive. So it takes too long for longer inputs.

Comment: The problem that you are trying to solve has the complexity of O(N^3). There is nothing you can do solve it faster than in polynomial time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a count instead of the actual triples you can do this in **O(n^2)** time. First create a list which indicates how many other numbers on the list can evenly divide the number. This takes **O(n^2)** time.

Then iterate the numbers starting from greatest to find all `z`, `y` pairs and for each pair add the value of `y` from list created on the first step to the result. This will also take **O(n^2)** time.

```
def solution(l):
    divs = [0] * len(l)

    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            if l[j] % l[i] == 0:
                divs[j] += 1

    result = 0
    for i in range(len(l) - 1, 1, -1):
        for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1):
            if l[i] % l[j] == 0:
                result += divs[j]

    return result

print(solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
print(solution(list(range(1, 2000))))
```

Output:

```
3
40777
```

**Update** Here's another solution that processes the list on one go:

```
def solution2(l):
    divs = [[0, 0] for _ in l]

    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            if l[j] % l[i] == 0:
                divs[j][0] += 1
                divs[j][1] += divs[i][0]

    return sum(x[1] for x in divs)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it! However at first there were test cases that failed. I removed the sort statement and it passed. Other than that, your solution is correct.

Comment: On my computer this function is slower than the original.

Comment: @johnjullies Maybe there's an extra requirement that the numbers have to be picked in the order they were in the original list (x index < y index < z index). Sorting would mess that up.

Comment: @MSeifert What if you try with input `[1] * 2000`?

Comment: @niemmi yes, that's what I thought too.

Comment: That `solution2` is quite nice! Will do some timings if you don't mind.

Comment: @MSeifert Sure, please add them to your answer. I'd expect it to be twice as fast as the original :)

Comment: How did you know?! It is 2x faster than the original. I'm not sure how my solution can be faster (includes 2 sortings and 2 nested loops)... (and sorry I forgot to upvote!)

Comment: @MSeifert Version 1 executes the nested loop twice, version 2 once. I'm not sure why your solution is faster. What I noticed during the execution is that it doesn't work with duplicates though (tried with input `[1] * 2000`).

Answer (score 2):

You can be faster if you create a mapping of all possible divisors and then count how many of the possible divisors have possible divisors.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def solution(l):
    l.sort(reverse=True)

    # The mapping will have each element as key and the possible divisors as value
    mapping = {}

    # Find all possible divisors for a number
    for idx, item in enumerate(l):
        # Use a set as value for faster lookups
        divisors = set()
        for other_item in l[idx+1:]:
            if item % other_item == 0:
                divisors.add(other_item)
        mapping[item] = divisors

    # Count the possibilities
    count = 0
    for z, ys in sorted(mapping.items(), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True):
        for y in ys:
            count += len(mapping[y])

    return count
```

To check the timings I used `%timeit` from IPython:

```
vals = list(range(1, 2000))
assert solution(vals) == your_solution(vals)
%timeit solution(vals)         # 1 loop, best of 3: 652 ms per loop
%timeit your_solution(vals)    # 1 loop, best of 3: 1.64 s per loop
# niemmi's solution only give the same solution when reversed.
vals = vals[::-1]
%timeit niemmi_solution(vals)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 1.99 s per loop
%timeit niemmi_solution2(vals) # 1 loop, best of 3: 1.01 s per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

from itertools import combinations

sum(1 for x, y, z in combinations(ns, 3) if y % x == 0 and z % y == 0)
Out[55]: 3
```

this did take a minute or two, definitely not the speed winner

```
sum(1 for x, y, z in combinations(list(range(1, 2000)), 3) if y % x == 0 and z % y == 0)
Out[56]: 40777
```